# AI-based services or software to auto-generate English subtitles for a non-English video as of April 2023?

Tags: video, language, translation, artificial-intelligence, transcription

A colleague of mine recently used [Whisper](https://openai.com/research/whisper) to auto-transcribe and translate a German video to English and the results were nothing short of mindblowing. So I wonder whether anyone has productized/commercialized this yet and offers a service to quickly auto-transcribe & translate uploaded videos (or audio tracks) to English in a common format like .srt? The service should support transcribing movie-length videos/tracks.

For specificity and to rule out opinion-based answers, I am primarily looking for services based on *Whisper* because I already know it meets my quality criteria. If you feel there are other models (and services) that provide similar quality, please mention them in the comments first (along with a link to a demo or similar), and I might then include them in my question.

Since this field is evolving *very fast*, I'm including the year/month in the question title. If this is not appropriate, please let me know.

Comment: This site is for asking about software not services